# Why we pass apikey,databaseurl,storageBucket,Domain, appId, messagingSenderId in Firebase Nodejs Project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

When initializing Firebase in Nodejs project, why we include `apikey`,`databaseurl`,`storageBucket`,`authDomain`, `appId`, `messagingSenderId`, `projectId` in Firebase.initializeApp()? Without some of these properties, it is still working, then why do we need to pass it?

And also for security, we use Firebase Authentication for checking user auth.uid, so why do we need to pass the above properties in initializeApp()?

Does passing these properties, Firebase will check it by default? If Firebase checks it by default, we don't need Firebase Authentication then?

I'm a beginner kindly help.

Comment: If my answer was useful you can accept ✔ and upvote  :) Feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase consists of >18 products these days, and many of them take different configuration data at startup. But since you only call `initializeApp` once for all these products, you have to pass the configuration data for all products in this one call.

That's why all example in the Firebase documentation and console show how to pass all possible configuration data. Depending on the products you actually use, and the platform you run on, you may need fewer of these values, but including all of them never causes problems.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you register an app with a Firebase project, the Firebase console provides a Firebase configuration file (Apple/Android apps) or a configuration object (web apps) that you add directly to your local app directory.

That is, a **Firebase config file** / **object** **associates an app with a specific Firebase project and its resources.** It consists of unique and non-secret identifiers for your project. A Firebase config file generally consists of **apiKey**, **databaseURL**, **projectId**, **storageBucket**, **messagingSenderId**, **appId**, **measurementId**.

These parameters are required by Firebase and Google services **to communicate with Firebase server APIs and to associate client data with the Firebase project and Firebase app**. The **apiKey** and the **projectId** are the **mandatory fields** in the configuration file/object. And, other fields are optional. Each of the other fields corresponds to an optional part of Firebase.

This is because Firebase contains many [services/products](https://firebase.google.com/products) such as realtime nosql database services, blob storage, push notifications/messaging, and ofcourse Authentication among many more things.
If you do not desire to use the other parts of Firebase, simply do not reference them nor enable them. It is completely fine to only use Firebase Authentication.

The **content** of the Firebase config file or object is **considered public**, including the app's platform-specific ID (Apple bundle ID or Android package name) and the Firebase project-specific values, like the API Key, project ID, Realtime Database URL, and Cloud Storage bucket name. Given this, it is recommended to **use Firebase Security Rules to protect your data and files** in Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, and Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks!